# Hiding an (active) app/game from search results

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-app-center, facebook-app-settings

We would like to hide a Facebook app from the generic search bar results ("apps" section), but keep the listing for the community page associated with the app. Is this possible?

We've tried changing a few app settings, but they do not appear to have any effect.

(App center -> App center listed platforms)

**Motivation/ goal**

Our app is implemented as a website (https://apps.facebook.com/genesforgood). In the past it was possible to use this directly within the Facebook Mobile App (similar to games that run in an iframe); as of this weekend this abruptly stopped working on iOS. (and has not been reachable within the FB Mobile App on Android for a while now)

Our community page has a "Use this app" hyperlink that takes the user to a website via the internal web browser- the link works correctly. We want this page to stay in search results as the single obvious way to use the app... but hide the "app" search listing, because that button does not work and is confusing users. A screenshot shows the distinction....

[image: sample search results]

...and the error when clicking the app result on mobile.

[image: sample "not available for phone" message]

**Other notes**

The breakage today does not seem to be part of an expected change, and the search/ error behavior has changed slightly since this morning.

Running via the desktop iframe still works, and our users seem to appreciate this method of using the app.

Comment: how this is programming related question?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski :  Because our app is in a broken state without it- configuration is part of making things work.

Slightly less cheekily, this is the recommended mechanism for in depth questions on facebook app development, and only another app developer is likely to have delved into the required internals of canvas.